CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey() fails with error CRYPT_E_NO_KEY_PROPERTY
This is the setup
AD CS (windows server 2019 Hyper-V VM)

Created a new template by duplicating smartcard logon template.
Changed provider to Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider.
Algorithm is RSA and minimum key size is 2048.    Purpose is set to
signature and encryption. Enabled "Allow private key to be exported".

client(windows 10 Hyper-V VM)

This machine is joined to domain which is same as AD CS.    Installed
AD CS root certificate to Trusted Root certificate authorities.
Request new certificate from the new template.    Got the
certificate and exported it to pfx file with private key and
password. while exporting selected these options "include all certificates in the certificate path if possible", "Enable certificate privacy".

when I try to import private key with following code, CertFindCertificateInStore() returns error CRYPT_E_NO_KEY_PROPERTY.
 HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(pfxPath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
 if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
     HandleError("Unable to open PFX file");
 }

 DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, nullptr);
 std::vector<BYTE> fileData(fileSize);
 DWORD bytesRead;
 if (!ReadFile(hFile, fileData.data(), fileSize, &bytesRead, nullptr) || bytesRead != fileSize) {
     HandleError("Unable to read PFX file");
 }

 CloseHandle(hFile);

 CRYPT_DATA_BLOB pfxBlob = { static_cast<DWORD>(fileData.size()), fileData.data() };
 if (!PFXIsPFXBlob(&pfxBlob)) {
     HandleError("Invalid PFX file");
 }

 hStore = PFXImportCertStore(&pfxBlob, password.c_str(), CRYPT_EXPORTABLE);

 if (!hStore) {
     HandleError("Failed to import PFX certificate store");
 }

 certContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_ANY, nullptr, nullptr);
 if (!certContext) {
     HandleError("Failed to find certificate in PFX store");
 }

 
 if (!CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(certContext, CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ONLY_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG, nullptr, &hCryptProvOrNCryptKey, &dwKeySpec, &fCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey)) {
     auto dw = GetLastError();
     HandleError("Failed to acquire private key");
 }

with self signed certificate, able to successfully import private key and export it as well.
I have tried passing 0 instead of CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ONLY_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG, but still same error.
Thanks for the help.

in pfx can be several certs, but you check only single cert. and this can be not final cert, which have private key


CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey returns error
CRYPT_E_NO_KEY_PROPERTY.

CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey look for CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID and if it not exist, return such error.
the PFXImportCertStore set on cert CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID in case PKCS12_NO_PERSIST_KEY not used or CERT_KEY_CONTEXT_PROP_ID if we use this flag. but this is not on all certificates in pfx, but only on cert which public key, correspond to private key from pfx. but you :

while exporting selected these options "include all certificates in
the certificate path if possible"

so several certificates was in pfx, and only one containing CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID or CERT_KEY_CONTEXT_PROP_ID property.
so instead CertFindCertificateInStore we need CertEnumCertificatesInStore and check every certificate in store, until found one "good".
also in most case better use PKCS12_NO_PERSIST_KEY, otherwise private key will be stored in new key container with autogenerated random name.
code can be look like:
CRYPT_DATA_BLOB PFX;
if (NOERROR ReadFromFile(pfxPath, &PFX.pbData, &PFX.cbData))
{
    if (HCERTSTORE hStore = PFXImportCertStore(&PFX, password, 
        CRYPT_EXPORTABLE|PKCS12_ALWAYS_CNG_KSP|PKCS12_NO_PERSIST_KEY))
    {
        PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = 0;
        while(pCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hStore, pCertContext))
        {
            CERT_KEY_CONTEXT ckc;
            ULONG cb = sizeof(ckc);
            if (CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCertContext, CERT_KEY_CONTEXT_PROP_ID, &ckc, &cb))
            {
                // use ckc.hNCryptKey
                // not need call NCryptFreeObject(ckc.hNCryptKey);
                CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
                break;
            }
        }
        CertCloseStore(hStore, 0);
    }
    LocalFree(PFX.pbData);
}

